# How to check if the image is saved [SWIFT]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can i check if the image saved or not ? 
I'm saving it this way:

```
library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!) { (url, error) -> Void in
```

After that i'm calling alertController and i need to make sure that it shows after the user allowed to save an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returning objects will be handled with the block, which is an **ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock**.

According to [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock):

```
ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock = (NSURL!, NSError!) -> Void
```

Where the **NSError** object `error` is described as:

> If the image is not saved, an error object that describes the reason
>   for failure, otherwise *nil*.

so in the block, you can do something like:

```
library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!) {
 (url, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        // Handle the error.
    } else {
        // Saved Successfully.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your NSURL `url` in `'(url, error)` is an assetURL, if the image is not saved, `url` is nil.
you will have to call you alertController in your completion block in case `url` is not `nil`.